# @Input() selected appearing false on first click (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building accordion components. The behavior I would like is for only one accordion (there are three total) to be open at a time. In other words, any open accordion should collapse when clicking any accordion besides the currently open one.

Right now, I am able to toggle these accordions open/close but I am unable to figure out how to 'select' them in order to apply the "collapse" class if it is not currently selected. My select input is false on first click (it is showing otherwise in Augury).

accordion-group.component.ts

```
import { AccordionComponent } from './../accordion/accordion.component';
import { Component, Input  } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-accordion-group',
  templateUrl: './accordion-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accordion-group.component.css']
})
export class AccordionGroupComponent {
  @Input() measures;
  selected

  select(i){
    this.selected = i;
  }
}
```

accordion-group.component.html

```
<app-accordion
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
[item]="item"
[selected]="i === selected"
(click)="select(i)">
</app-accordion>
```

accordion.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-accordion",
  templateUrl: "./accordion.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./accordion.component.css"]
})
export class AccordionComponent {
  @Input() item;
  @Input() index;
  @Input() selected //this needs to receive true on selected component on click


  expand: string = "";
  isOpen = false;

  handleExpansion() {
    console.log(this.selected) //logs false on first click
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

    this.isOpen ? (this.expand = "expand") : (this.expand = "collapse");
  }
}
```

accordion.component.html

```
<div
(click)="handleExpansion()"
class="accordion noHighlight {{expand}}">
</div>
```

Comment: The click handler in `AccordionComponent` will execute before the one in `AccordionGroupComponent` since events bubble up. This is the expected behavior. Have you thought about listening for changes to the `selected` property and remove the click handler in the `AccordianComponent`?

Comment: how would I go about doing this? Move the click handler to the Accordion component? How would I communicate to each accordion sibling that it should close if not currently selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the reason that you are experiencing this is because browser DOM events bubble up. So, your click handler in the `AccordionComponent` will execute before the one in the `AccordionGroupComponent`.

There are a bunch of ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, so I put together [a quick Plunker for you](https://plnkr.co/edit/WTMg5g3UWMM04x40hWEW?p=preview) with one way of doing it.

The gist of it is that the group determines which accordion is expanded (if any):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-accordion-group',
    template: `
        <app-accordion *ngFor="let accordion of accordions" [title]="accordion.title"
            [isExpanded]="accordion === expandedAccordion"
            (expandClick)="processExpandClick(accordion, $event)">
            <p>{{ accordion.description }}</p>
        </app-accordion>
    `
})
export class AccordionGroupComponent {
    @Input() accordions: Accordion[];

    expandedAccordion: Accordion = null;

    processExpandClick(accordion: Accordion, isExpanded: boolean) {
        this.expandedAccordion = isExpanded ? accordion : null;
    }
}
```

And the accordion emits out events when an expand/collapse event occurs, allowing the group to determine what to expand/collapse:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-accordion",
    template: `
        <div class="accordion" [class.expanded]="isExpanded">
            <div (click)="handleClick()">
                <span *ngIf="!isExpanded">+</span>
                <span *ngIf="isExpanded">-</span>
                {{ title }}
            </div>
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .accordion__content {
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .expanded .accordion__content {
            height: auto;
        }
    `]
})
export class AccordionComponent {
    @Input() title;
    @Input() isExpanded = false;
    @Output() expandClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    handleClick() {
        this.expandClick.emit(!this.isExpanded);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an example, this helped my problem.

Comment: How would you go about only applying a 'collapse' class on first click?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have a 'collapse' animation being applied when isExpanded is false. Because it's false by default on load, the animation causes all accordions to collapse - or go from open to close automatically when you first load the page.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, like I said, there are a bunch of ways to handle this. The assumption in my example was that at most one would be exapanded. It sounds like you want the case where they all can be opened. In that case, you can hold onto the isExpanded state of all accordions and default them all to be expanded. Here is an updated Plunker showing one quick way of doing that: https://plnkr.co/edit/WTMg5g3UWMM04x40hWEW?p=preview